# asp.net c# wait operation time out

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have ASP.Net Project that was running perfectly.
But i want that it automatically refresh and for that i added the one line of Code in Page Load

Code : `Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "30");`

After added this code it run successfully 4 or 5 times but after that
it gives an Error

```
The wait operation timed out

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

So what i do for that Exception.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012 ASP.Net C#.

Answer (score 1):

I test the same line in page load event

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "5");
```

but no error occurred even after 10 minutes. error is generated by some other line of code you must search out or share the whole page.

second way:(you should try this)

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "refresh",      "window.setTimeout('window.location.reload(true);',5000);", true);

    }
}
```

Third way:(by using HTML META Tag)

Add the tag in head portion. This might not be recommended when you are using latest technologies like AJAX.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=Dashboard.aspx">
```

Comment: In the above method, what is the best way.